# Displaying a .txt file in Flask

Tags: python, html, file, flask, upload

So I'm trying to make a program using Flask that will allow users to upload a .txt file. The program will then print out this file. Using some tutorials I've found, I have the following code in a file called site.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def upload():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        content = f.read()
    return render_template("book.html", content=content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Inside of my 'upload.html' file I have the following:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

and inside of my book.html file I have the following:

```
<pre>
{{ text }}
</pre>
```

The file uploader is definitely working - the files are being saved in the correct directory in my computer, but the text in the files isn't being displayed, namely the last two lines of my site.py:

```py
        content = f.read()
    return render_template("book.html", content=content)
```

don't seem to be doing anything.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing the 'content' variable to 'text' variable?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: On the render template method, you passed 'content=content'. You should pass something like 'text=content'

Comment: hmm okay that makes sense, I tried changing the line to: return render_template("book.html", text=content) but now I just get the following output, no matter what file I put in: b'' - like instead of printing out the .txt file it just prints out b''

Answer (score 1):

I think your question should be "How to display a .txt file content  inside an html `pre` tag with Flask" instead of yours, cuz It is little different meaning
Although just watching your code, You only have to send the correct context keyword to the template, like @alexander-santos said too:

```
return render_template("book.html", text=content)
```

Comment: I tried this, and though it definitely is a step in the right direction, for some reason when I do this, I get the following output: b'', no matter what the text file is.  I tried modifying the book.html file to print something, to make sure it was working, and it did print it. But, for some reason, the line `{{ text }}` doesn't seem to be working properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be that your file is bad/corrupted, or your operating system has permissions on you media folder, check this out, and tell us what it is wrong!  Although It is important to save a file in binary mode, with encoding utf-8. All those details are important in order to render well a document txt